# How to get all node's relationships in neo4j using Java Connector Jar

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

Here's my graph

[image]

I'm trying to get the details of the nodes and its relationship in java code and below is my code. I'm able to get the details of the nodes but not the relationships. And the java docs has no information and methods that allow exposing of the relationships.

**My Code**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.Result;
import org.neo4j.driver.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.Value;
import org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult;

public class Neo4jTest {

    private Driver driver;

    public Neo4jTest() {
        loadDriver();
    }

    private void loadDriver() {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "Test"));
    }

    public Result createNodes(String query) {
        try (Session session = driver.session())
        {
            InternalResult result = (InternalResult) session.writeTransaction(tx -> tx.run(query));
            return result;
        }
    }

    public List<Record> execute(String query) {
        try (Session session = driver.session())
        {
            Result result = session.run(query);
            return result.list();
        }
    }

    public void cleanUp(String object) {
        String cleanUpQuery = "match(n:" + object +") detach delete n";
        execute(cleanUpQuery);
    }

    public void printResults(List<Record> results) {
        for (Record record : results) {
            Value rec = record.get("n");
            System.out.print("Record --> [");
            for (String key : rec.keys()) {
                System.out.print(key + " : " + rec.get(key) + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("]");

            //TODO: Need to get all Relationship of this particular node
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String createQuery = "create \n" + 
                "(a:People {name : \"Vivek\", age : 20}), \n" + 
                "(b:People {name : \"Abdul\", age : 25}), \n" + 
                "(c:People {name : \"John\", age : 22}),\n" + 
                "" +
                "(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b),\n" + 
                "(b)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(c),\n" + 
                "(c)-[:KNOWS]->(a)";

        String fetchQuery = "match(n:People) return n";

        Neo4jTest obj = new Neo4jTest();
        obj.cleanUp("People");

        // Create Nodes
        obj.createNodes(createQuery);

        // Fetch Nodes
        List<Record> results = obj.execute(fetchQuery);

        // Process Results
        obj.printResults(results);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Record --> [name : "Vivek", age : 20, ]
Record --> [name : "Abdul", age : 25, ]
Record --> [name : "John", age : 22, ]
```

**JavaDoc Link** -> https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/

**Relevant Result Objects**

```
org.neo4j.driver.Record;
org.neo4j.driver.Value;
```

**Other Details**

Neo4j Community Version - 3.5.14

Neo4j Java Driver Version - 4.0.0

**Update**

(for cybersam answer)

The first query doesn't return the relationship as part of the r variable. 
[image]

[Update] And the second query also doesn't return relationship
[image]

Results in the neo4j browser and code are the same.

Output for query

MATCH (n:People) WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes MATCH (:People)-[r]->(:People) WITH nodes, COLLECT(TYPE(r)) AS rels RETURN nodes, rels

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

The current `fetchQuery` is only requesting and returning nodes.

You could use this instead (and make appropriate changes to `printResults`):

```
String fetchQuery = "MATCH (n:People)-[r]-(m:People) RETURN n, r, m";
```

Or, you could use this (which returns separate lists for `People` nodes and the relationships between them, but is less efficient):

```
String fetchQuery =
  "MATCH (n:People) WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes " +
  "MATCH (:People)-[r]->(:People) WITH nodes, COLLECT(r) AS rels" +
  "RETURN nodes, rels";
```

*By the way, `People` should really be `Person` since each node is for 1 person.*

[ADDENDUM]

To see the type and end nodes of each relationship:

```
String fetchQuery =
  "MATCH (a:People)-[r]->(b:People) " +
  "RETURN TYPE(r) AS type_r, a, b";
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the above didn't work. Kindly check my update section and throw some more light on it.

Comment: Fixed my code. The second `WITH` needs to pass `nodes`, otherwise it becomes unbound.

Comment: Hi cybersam, the second query runs now but doesn't return relationship, kindly check the update.

Comment: The query is returning the relationships (that is why `rels` shows multiple maps), but your relationships have no properties (so the maps are empty). For instance, you can use `COLLECT(TYPE(r))` instead of `COLLECT(r)` to see the relationship types instead. Or you can add properties to your relationships.

Comment: COLLECT(TYPE(r)) -> returns all the relationship collectively and not of the individual nodes. Kindly check the updated image

Comment: See `ADDENDUM` to my answer. This is a very basic Cypher query.

Comment: Great, I just figured it out using google, but i'll mark your answer as the right one. Just reorder the answer. Thanks for your time. Can i have your email id?